# Is there a problem with the close-vote queue?

Tags: discussion, review

I have noticed, that there were some threads on this topic in the past, such like this one: [My problem with the closing brigade](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18799/my-problem-with-the-closing-brigade)

I did not fully read those questions, but I think there is something wrong with it in a pretty fundamental way.

In the past weeks I was banned two times for a few day from any review queue, because I did not vote to close questions. Thats what I wrote about here: [Why does it take 5 close votes, to close a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30172/why-does-it-take-5-close-votes-to-close-a-question)

The thing is, that I started to mindlessly vote to close questions.
Seriously, I do not invest any noteable time what so ever into these close votes. I just make sure I do not run into an audit.

What has happend? Nothing.
I just smash the close button and no one seems to bother.
I do this for the past 4-5 days now.

When I reviewed with my humble opinion, I was banned in a blink.
And now, that I really do not care anymore, everything is fine?

I think there is something really wrong here. Espacially with my banns in the past and I think that the 'rules' what makes a question close worthy, should be adapted in some way.

Often you see questions which got closed, which have some favorites, a decent amount of upvotes and completly fine answers (often not even just one answer), so what is the point in closing these questions? I do not understand.

In the first link I gave there was spoken about an 'unfriendly welcome' to new users, and that is what I think too.

Closing a question is just rude.
I do not say, that no question should be closed, but I am pretty sure, that 4 out of 5 closed questions do not deserve to be closed.

So again, I might ask:

> Why does it take 5 close votes, for a question to be closed, when I can just vote to close every single question and no one seems to care about it?

Comment: Just as a comment, I know on occasion I use Favorites to track questions I think are far from good questions, so I don't think that really has to say anything about question quality. Just "i want to be able to find this later."

Answer (score 7):

There are two orthogonal  aspects to this.

- What is true is that to vote to close in the close queue is arguably 'easier' than to not vote to close, since one swims with the flow so to say. The point is a question in the close queue is usually only there since somebody already thought that it should be closed thus it is to be expected that there is a (considerably) higher than average percentage of close worthy questions there.
- What is not true is that we do nothing about users that close everything. We  do not expose individual user, so I will not name anyone specifically but fact is users do get review-banned for closing 'too much' as well (even users generally in good standing of which we believe they in principle act in good faith). That you did not get noticed is a combination of coincidence and statistical effects, mostly the second. At the moment you switched your average does not switch instantly but smoothly, once the average  moved considerably it seems you actually reduced the close voting. At the time of writing, you don't vote to close everything.

That said, it's definitely possible to review ultimately absurdly and not get noticed. Say, a user closing everything in the morning and leaving open everything in the evening might well not be noticed for quite a while if they pay attention to audits, since the average is about reasonable. In practice, that's I think not that much of a problem since it does not have much impact overall and is arather boring way of trolling.

Comment: I am still just closing questions I would have closed befor on my no-close-policy, where I was banned immediatly.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to say. Could you please state it differently or in more detail.

Comment: When I consider a question close worthy, then I close it, of course. It is not that I just close everything. Edit: Or to say better, when I really think a question should not be closed, I do not close it (or vote to close).

Comment: I do not quite understand why you would expect to face any problems when you do not vote to close any questions you think should not be closed.

Comment: I have no number on how many threads I vote not to close. Mostly I did when I expected an audit. The thing is, that I just close most questions. And when I just skipped them, or did not vote to close I was banned immediatly. Basically all that stands in the post above, or I do not understand you... But I already see, that this discussion leads nowhere and there is no point in discussing or to care about it. If you delete your answer, I can delete this thread. I do not mind.

Comment: If you are generally of the opinion that too many questions get closed or the criteria for this should be different, then to frame the discussion differently might be a good idea. The focus on the close-review queue is not ideal and a distraction to this. Further, as explained, the place to try to change general practice regarding what is and is not closed is *not* the close review-queue the point of the queue is to implement the current guidelines. To change the guidelines is in principle possible, yet not via not following them in the review-queues.

Comment: Differently, the close-queue seems to work well enough to implement the current guidelines. If you have a problem with the guidelines, don't blame the queue or those that oversee it (in that capacity).